# No response after filling in the Email Markup registration

Tags: google-schemas

Sent registration Gmail Email markUp (adding schemas to the templates of letters)

I sent a letter with a markup to 
schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com 
and passed the test 
https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/?hl=ru

Foldings did not come, and more than a week there is no answer.
Tell me, what is the approximate length of the answer, should the pile come and should I write again?

Comment: It's been a week I've submitted and still waiting for a reply too!

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience in requesting to whitelist a specific email address, usually, it takes about 2 weeks in total to complete the process. Just make sure that the following guidelines in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) was met to avoid rejection.

Answer (score 0):

will everyone get a reply if application was rejected or approved?