# How long does the whitelisting process take?

Tags: google-schemas

How long the approval process takes. We already sent a test email to schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com and filled out the registration. How long the application process typically takes before we should expect to hear something back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my answer here: [No response after filling in the Email Markup registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425739/no-response-after-filling-in-the-email-markup-registration?rq=1)

> As per my experience in requesting to whitelist a specific email address, usually, it takes about 2 weeks in total to complete the process. Just make sure that the following guidelines in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) was met to avoid rejection.